# How to test the bundle version string from within the app (ASObjC)

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to implement a "check for software updates" function in my ASObjC app.

I'm more or less there, except I'm not quite sure how to query the current version number in my info.plist from within my application's script.

Suppose I have the newest version number in an html file which I call using curl. I display a dialog prompting the user to update if the version number curl returns is higher than the version number of the calling script.

How do I get the bundles current version number into a property in the script to test against what's returned by curl?

I discovered the constant "CFBundleShortVersionString" but my attempts to use it have been thwarted.

This doesn't work, for example:

set myVersionNum to current application's CFBundleShortVersionString

I tried coercing to string and text to no avail.

EDIT: it appears the following works:

set myVersionNum to current application's version

Answer (score 0):

The NSBundle class does have an method `objectForInfoDictionaryKey:` which is an method to get the value of the given key of the bundle's info.plist file. So when we use the application's main bundle (itself) then we could easily get the value with the following method:

```
set appBundle to current application's class "NSBundle"'s mainBundle()
set shortVersionString to appBundle's objectForInfoDictionaryKey:"CFBundleShortVersionString"
```

*note: I use the new Mavericks (AppleScript 2.3) AppleScriptObjC syntax.*